# remove the dashes that appear at the top

Tags: listings

Using the listings package I tried to mimic the Matlab R2016a environment with the following code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[breaklinks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage{multirow,array}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstdefinestyle{matlab}{ 
       language     = Matlab,
       basicstyle   = \small,
       breaklines   = true,
       numbers      = left,
       numberstyle  = \small,
       stepnumber   = 1 --,  
       commentstyle = \color{green!90!black!95}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[style=matlab]
  % Pregunta 1
  N = 500;
  n = 0:N-1;
  x = sin(5*pi*n/358);
  p = seqperiod(x)
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

resulting in:
[image]

In the figure you can see how dashes appear at the top, this is given by placing "stepnumber = 1- -", but it's the only thing I found that generates the dashes.

Is there a way to remove those dashes from the top or is there another option to generate those dashes in code?

Comment: Do not use option `stepnumber` but redefine `\thelstnumber` instead. E.g.: `\renewcommand\thelstnumber{\the\value{lstnumber} --}`

Answer (score 1):

Is this helpful?

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[breaklinks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage{multirow,array,xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstdefinestyle{matlab}{ 
       language     = Matlab,
       basicstyle   = \small,
       breaklines   = true,
       numbers      = left,
       numberstyle  = \small,
       stepnumber   = 1,  
       commentstyle = \color{green!90!black!95}
}
\renewcommand\thelstnumber{\arabic{lstnumber}--}
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[style=matlab]
  % Pregunta 1
  N = 500;
  n = 0:N-1;
  x = sin(5*pi*n/358);
  p = seqperiod(x)
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

As `Andreas Matthias` already pointed this suggestion in his `comment`....